# How do you change the position of the boundingRect() of a QGraphicsItem on a QGraphicsScene?

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have set the `boundingRect()` of my `QGraphicsItem` to a certain coordinate on the scene. How can I change the coordinates based on the `QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent`?

---

Below is the code I have written. But this code only sets the position of the shape I drew within the `boundingRect()` to a coordinate inside the `boundingRect()`. What I want to be able to do is move the entire `QGraphicsItem` to a set coordinate.

```
void QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);

    if (y()>=394 && y()<425) //if in the range between 425 and 394 I want it to move to 440.
    {
        setPos(440, y());
    }
    else if ... //Other ranges such as that in the first if statement
    {
        ... //another y coordinate
    }
    else //If the item is not in any of the previous ranges it's y coordinate is set to 0
    {
        setPos(0,y()); //I had expected the item to go to y = 0 on the scene not the boundingRect()
    }

}
```

The scene is 880 by 860 and the `boundingRect()` is set like this:

```
QRectF QGraphicsItem::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(780,425,60,30);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bounding rect of an item defines the item in its **local coordinates**, whereas setting its position in the scene is using **scene coordinates**.

For example, let's create a skeleton `Square` class, derived from `QGraphicsItem`

```
class Square : public QGraphicsItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    Square(int size)
        : QGraphicsItem(NULL) // we could parent, but this may confuse at first
    {
        m_boundingRect = QRectF(0, 0, size, size);
    }

    QRectF boundingRect() const
    {
        return m_boundingRect;
    }

private:
    QRectF m_boundingRect;
};
```

We can create a square with width and height of 10

```
Square* square = new Square(10);
```

If the item is added to a `QGraphicsScene`, it will appear at the top-left of the scene (0, 0);

```
pScene->addItem(square); // assuming the Scene has been instantiated.
```

Now we can move the `square` in the scene...

```
square->setPos(100, 100);
```

The `square` will move, but its width and height are still 10 units. If the bounding rect of the `square` is changed, then the rect itself changes, but its position in the scene is still the same. Let's resize the `square`...

```
void Square::resize(int size)
{
    m_boundingRect = QRectF(0, 0, size, size);
}

square->resize(100);
```

The `square` now has width and height of 100, but its position is the same and we can can move the `square` separately from its defined bounding rect

```
square->setPos(200, 200);
```

> What I want to be able to do is move the entire QGraphicsItem to a set coordinate.

So, hopefully this has explained that the bounding rect is the internal (local coordinate) representation of the item, and to move the item, just call `setPos`, which will move the item relative to any parent, or if no parent exists, it will move it relative to the scene.